# Use Notepad++ to convert file content format

Tags: notepad++, regex, database

So, I have a database with the records that I export to a file and within this file the data records are in this format:

```
date of registration;username;email:hashed password
```

---

**Examples**

```
24-05-2015;metternich;test@gmail.com:4f859c0bca674c6b1806834a1e2b772b
```

or

```
<Date>;<UserName>;<EmailAddress>:<PasswordHash>
```

---

**Notepad++**

I'm having trouble using **Notepad++** to help me reformat the data in this file into a format such as:

```
<Date>;<UserName>
<EmailAddress>:<PasswordHash>
```

---

**Question**

How would I do that, using Notepad++ using RegEx to help me tranform this data?

Comment: So you want to split one database into two?

Comment: ehm, yes, kinda, it's almost the same.

Comment: Do you mean a database table? Can you post an example of an input file and expected output for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace the second semicolon with a linebreak

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^;]+;[^;]+\K;`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n` depending on your needs
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
[^;]+   : 1 or more any character that is not a semicolo
;       : a semicolon
[^;]+   : 1 or more any character that is not a semicolo
\K      : forget all we have seen until this position
;       : a semicolon
```

**Result for given example:**

```
24-05-2015;metternich
test@gmail.com:4f859c0bca674c6b1806834a1e2b772b
```

Comment: @kamilleon: OK for for the edit. If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)